# a button in a data grid table flutter with a bool value

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

i need to make a button for each row that changes the state of the
bool "that can't be a widget" from false to true
the data table takes info from an api
i need the button to work so that i can change the state as i explained above.

*edit from last time
i added a Container () with a child ,
*not to forget the properties of the container and the text inside the child and so on as below.

```
 Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: Colors.blue,
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)
),
  child: Center(child: FlatButton(onPressed: () { Text(
    row.getCells()[5].value.bool(),
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
  );  },
    child: Center( child: Text('state', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),)),
  )),
  ),
```

below is the whole deal, without the future because i don't think it has something to do with it specifically   because all of what the data grid needs is below

```
semi full code:

class ProductDataGridSource extends DataGridSource {
  ProductDataGridSource(this.list) {
    buildDataGridRow();
  }
  late List<DataGridRow> dataGridRows;
  late List<MaintenanceDetailsByDriverNo> list;

  @override
  DataGridRowAdapter? buildRow(DataGridRow row) {
    return DataGridRowAdapter(cells: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(
            row.getCells()[0].value,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(
            row.getCells()[1].value,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              row.getCells()[2].value.toString(),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              row.getCells()[3].value.toString(),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              row.getCells()[4].value.toString(),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.blue,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)
    ),
      child: Center(child: FlatButton(onPressed: () { Text(
        row.getCells()[5].value.bool(),
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
      );  },
        child: Center( child: Text('الحالة', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),)),
      )),
      ),
    ],);
  }

    


   @override
  List<DataGridRow> get rows => dataGridRows;

  void buildDataGridRow() {
    dataGridRows = list.map<DataGridRow>((dataGridRow) {
      return DataGridRow(cells: [
        DataGridCell(columnName: 'نوع الصيانة', value: dataGridRow.faultName),
        DataGridCell<String>(
            columnName: 'مكان الصيانة', value: dataGridRow.faultLocationName),
        DataGridCell<String>(
            columnName: 'اسم السائق', value: dataGridRow.driverName),
        DataGridCell<int>(
            columnName: 'رقم العملية', value: dataGridRow.iD),
        DataGridCell<String>(
            columnName: 'التاريخ', value: dataGridRow.faultDate),
       DataGridCell<bool>(columnName: 'الحاله', value: dataGridRow.isSelected),
      ]);
    }).toList(growable: false);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting ***that can't be a widget*** It would be better if you could provide full widget of [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: but if you continue reading i solved the issue with wrapping it with a child and giving it all possible properties. Now i am trying to make it change the state of bool from false to true.

Comment: ***i solved the issue with wrapping*** did you solve the issue?

Comment: no i didnot it should change the bool from false to true.

Comment: Are you using [syncfusion_flutter_datagrid](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datagrid)

Comment: yes i am using it ,

Comment: # is till need help because i haven't figured it out yet. the sf data grid doesnot take in set state , so i require help, anyone ?